# Moved storyboarded menu leaves an inaccessible area

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Driving me crazy. I have a centered menu in XAML which I shrink and move to one side in order to use the entire screen area. This all works but the area where the menu was i.e. the center is now inaccessible, it won't respond to clicks etc.

Comment: I'll build a workaround.

Comment: Did you check that the panel owning this menu have a Background set (even a Transparent one) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the XAML and make sure you don't have a transparent control positioned over your menu.